# If statement keeps giving same value regardless of user input

Tags: python, if-statement, game-development

I am making a pokemon guessing game where the height and type are given, all works well except for one thing, the height checker.

The height checker is supposed to tell if the pokemon you guessed is taller or smaller than the pokemon that was chosen. Regardless of user input, the output is always `the pokemon is a little taller than what you chose`. The code is below:

```
import random
life = 4

genone = ["Bulbasaur", "Ivysaur", "Venusaur", "Charmander ", "Charmeleon", "Charizard",
          "Squirtle", "Wartortle", "Blastoise", "Caterpie", "Metapod", "Butterfree",
          "Weedle", "Kakuna", "Beedrill", "Pidgey", "Pidgeotto", "Pidgeot", "Rattata",
          "Raticate", "Spearow", "Fearow", "Ekans", "Arbok", "Pikachu", "Raichu",
          "Sandshrew", "Sandslash", "Nidoran♀", "Nidorina", "Nidoqueen", "Nidoran♂",
          "Nidorino", "Nidoking", "Clefairy", "Clefable", "Vulpix", "Ninetales"
          "random poke"]
genonetypes = ["grass", "grass", "grass", "fire ", "fire", "fire/dragon", "water",
               "water", "water", "bug", "bug", "bug", "bug", "bug", "bug", "flying",
               "flying", "flying", "normal", "normal", "flying", "flying", "poison",
               "poison", "electric", "electric", "ground", "ground", "poison", "poison",
               "poison", "poison", "poison", "poison", "fairy", "fairy", "fire", "fire",
               "tester"]
genoneheight = ["0.7m", "1m", "2m", "0.6m", "1.1m", "1.7m", "0.5m", "1m", "1.6m", "0.3m",
                "0.7m", "1.1m", "0.3m", "0.6m", "1m", "0.3m", "1.1m", "1.5m", "0.3m",
                "0.3m", "0.7m","0.3m","1.2m","2m","3.5m","0.4m","0.8m","0.6m","1m","0.4m",
                "0.8m", "1.3m","0.5m","0.9m","1.4m","0.6","1.3","0.6m","1.1","4m"]
x, y, z = random.choice(list(zip(genone,genonetypes,genoneheight)))


while True:
    print(x)
    print(z)
    print("The pokemon type is " + y + " and they are " + z + " tall (meters)")
    userin = input("enter the pokemon you think it is: ")

    if userin.lower() == x.lower():
        print("yes!!! great job you got it!!!11!!!!")
        break

    if userin != x:
        life = life-1
        print("that is incorrect you have " + str(life) + " lives left\n")
        print()

    # height check
    if userin > z:
        print("the pokemon is a little taller than what you chose")
    if userin < z:
        print("the pokemon is a little smaller than what you chose")

    if life == 0:
        print("the pokemon was " + x + " .")
        print("better luck next time")
        break
```

Is there an issue with the `if` statement or where it is placed?

Answer (score 1):

In order to compare heights you need the height of the random selection and that of the pokeman guess the user typed in. To make getting the latter easier, I've created a lookup-table `lut` dictionary that maps pokemon names to their type and height. The table is created with relatively succint [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and looks like this:

```
{'bulbasaur': ('grass', '0.7m'),
 'ivysaur': ('grass', '1m'),
 'venusaur': ('grass', '2m'),
 'charmander ': ('fire ', '0.6m'),
 'charmeleon': ('fire', '1.1m'),
 'charizard': ('fire/dragon', '1.7m'),
 'squirtle': ('water', '0.5m'),
 'wartortle': ('water', '1m'),
 'blastoise': ('water', '1.6m'),
 'caterpie': ('bug', '0.3m'),
 'metapod': ('bug', '0.7m'),
 'butterfree': ('bug', '1.1m'),
 'weedle': ('bug', '0.3m'),
 'kakuna': ('bug', '0.6m'),
 'beedrill': ('bug', '1m'),
 'pidgey': ('flying', '0.3m'),
 'pidgeotto': ('flying', '1.1m'),
 'pidgeot': ('flying', '1.5m'),
 'rattata': ('normal', '0.3m'),
 'raticate': ('normal', '0.3m'),
 'spearow': ('flying', '0.7m'),
 'fearow': ('flying', '0.3m'),
 'ekans': ('poison', '1.2m'),
 'arbok': ('poison', '2m'),
 'pikachu': ('electric', '3.5m'),
 'raichu': ('electric', '0.4m'),
 'sandshrew': ('ground', '0.8m'),
 'sandslash': ('ground', '0.6m'),
 'nidoran?': ('poison', '1m'),
 'nidorina': ('poison', '0.4m'),
 'nidoqueen': ('poison', '0.8m'),
 'nidoran?': ('poison', '1.3m'),
 'nidorino': ('poison', '0.5m'),
 'nidoking': ('poison', '0.9m'),
 'clefairy': ('fairy', '1.4m'),
 'clefable': ('fairy', '0.6m'),
 'vulpix': ('fire', '1.3m'),
 'ninetalesrandom poke': ('fire', '0.6m')}
```

With this table and a helper function named `to_float()` that converts the height string into a floating point number to make proper numeric value comparisons, I came up with the following:

```
import random
life = 4

genome = ["Bulbasaur", "Ivysaur", "Venusaur", "Charmander ", "Charmeleon", "Charizard",
          "Squirtle", "Wartortle", "Blastoise", "Caterpie", "Metapod", "Butterfree",
          "Weedle", "Kakuna", "Beedrill", "Pidgey", "Pidgeotto", "Pidgeot", "Rattata",
          "Raticate", "Spearow", "Fearow", "Ekans", "Arbok", "Pikachu", "Raichu",
          "Sandshrew", "Sandslash", "Nidoran♀", "Nidorina", "Nidoqueen", "Nidoran♂",
          "Nidorino", "Nidoking", "Clefairy", "Clefable", "Vulpix", "Ninetales"
          "random poke"]
genometypes = ["grass", "grass", "grass", "fire ", "fire", "fire/dragon", "water",
               "water", "water", "bug", "bug", "bug", "bug", "bug", "bug", "flying",
               "flying", "flying", "normal", "normal", "flying", "flying", "poison",
               "poison", "electric", "electric", "ground", "ground", "poison", "poison",
               "poison", "poison", "poison", "poison", "fairy", "fairy", "fire", "fire",
               "tester"]
genomeheight = ["0.7m", "1m", "2m", "0.6m", "1.1m", "1.7m", "0.5m", "1m", "1.6m", "0.3m",
                "0.7m", "1.1m", "0.3m", "0.6m", "1m", "0.3m", "1.1m", "1.5m", "0.3m",
                "0.3m", "0.7m","0.3m","1.2m","2m","3.5m","0.4m","0.8m","0.6m","1m","0.4m",
                "0.8m", "1.3m","0.5m","0.9m","1.4m","0.6m","1.3m","0.6m","1.1m","4m"]

# Create lookup table.
lut = {name.lower(): (type, height)
        for (name, (type, height)) in zip(genome, zip(genometypes, genomeheight))}

# Utility function.
def to_float(text):
    """Return text string converted to float."""
    # Ignore last character unless it a digit.
    end = -1 if not text[-1].isdigit() else len(text)
    return float(text[:end])


# Randomly select genome and get associated information.
x, y, z = random.choice(list(zip(genome, genometypes, genomeheight)))
# x, (y, z) = 'ivysaur', lut['ivysaur']  # Hardcode for testing.

while True:
    print(x)
    print(z)
    print("The pokemon type is " + y + " and they are " + z + " tall (meters)")
    userin = input("Enter the pokemon you think it is: ").lower()

    if userin not in lut:
        print("Sorry, that's a unrecognized pokemon. Please try again.")
        continue

    if userin == x:
        print("Yes!!! Great job you got it!!!!!!!")
        break
    else:
        life -= 1
        print("That is incorrect you have " + str(life) + " lives left\n")
        print()

    if life == 0:
        print("The pokemon was " + x + " .")
        print("Better luck next time")
        break

    # Height check.
    userin_height = to_float(lut[userin][1])  # Get height of associated pokemon.
    float_z = to_float(z)  # Convert to float.

    if userin_height > float_z:
        print("The pokemon is a little smaller than what you chose")
    elif userin_height < float_z:
        print("The pokemon is a little taller than what you chose")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to keep track of the variables `userin` and `z`.
From your program, `userin` is supposed to be the "genone" (eg. Bulbasaur) while `z` is a string of height (eg. "0.7m").
So with conditional statement such as `if userin < z`, you are comparing two different things (eg. "genone" < "0.7m"). As for string comparison, '0' is smaller than 'g' so you will always have `the pokemon is a little taller than what you chose` printed.

What you will have to do is to, first, find the "genoneheight" of the "genone", and then compare this height with the "genoneheight" of the chosen pokemon.

A more convenient way to do this is to define a dictionary with genone as key, and genonetypes and genoneheight as values.

Comment: While your explanation of what's wrong is admirable, the explanations of how to fix them doesn't go far enough IMO.

Answer (score 0):

`userin` is the name of the pokemon I suppose. `userin` is always going to be greater than `z` in this case.

What you must do is:

```
if genoneheight[genone.index(userin)] > z:
   print('Taller')
else:
   print('Shorter')
```

This gets the element in the index of index position of `userin` in genone from genoneheight. This may sound confusing. Please reply if it worked. Also, I suggest you to use `float` instead of `str` for the heights.

Comment: When I do this it gives the error saying pokemon is not in the list.

Comment: It must work. Could i know what the values of `userin`, `x`, `y` and `z` are? It works on my system.